# RESTful web service with JSON : PUT and DELETE not working

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to set up a simple RESTful web service on Netbeans. Basicly, I have a container where the components are simple order objects with 3 attributes : id, total, and list of items.
    The GET and the POST on the container work fine as well as the GET on the components. What is not working is the PUT and the DELETE on the components: I don't receive any error, just nothing happens.
    Since the GET is working, probably the error is on the client side, so I am posting the client class in charge of the single orders here.

```
package restclientjson;

    import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;


    public class JSONOrderClient {

        private WebTarget webTarget;
        private Client client;
        private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RESTServerJSON/webresources";

        public JSONOrderClient(String id) {
            client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
            String resourcePath = java.text.MessageFormat.format("orders/{0}", new Object[]{id});
            webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path(resourcePath);
        }

        public void setResourcePath(String id) {
            String resourcePath = java.text.MessageFormat.format("orders/{0}", new Object[]{id});
            webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path(resourcePath);
        }

        public void putJson(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
            webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }

        public void delete() throws ClientErrorException {
            webTarget.request().delete();
        }

        public <T> T getJson(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
            WebTarget resource = webTarget;
            return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
        }

        public void close() {
            client.close();
        }

    }
```

Edit: Here is the Server side code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ServiceCore;

import dto.Order;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service OrderResource
 *
 * 
 */
public class OrderResource {

    private String id;
    private Map<String,Order> orderMap;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of OrderResource
     */
    private OrderResource(String id,Map<String,Order> orderMap) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderMap = orderMap;
    }

    /**
     * Get instance of the OrderResource
     */
    public static OrderResource getInstance(String id,Map<String,Order> orderMap) {
        // The user may use some kind of persistence mechanism
        // to store and restore instances of OrderResource class.
        return new OrderResource(id,orderMap);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of ServiceCore.OrderResource
     * @return an instance of dto.Order
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Order getJson() {
        return orderMap.get(id);
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of OrderResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(Order content) {
        orderMap.put(id, content);
    }

    /**
     * DELETE method for resource OrderResource
     */
    @DELETE
    public void delete() {
        orderMap.remove(id);
    }
}



package ServiceCore;

import dto.Order;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    /**
     * REST Web Service
     *
     */
    @Path("/orders")
    public class OrdersResource {

        @Context
        private UriInfo context;

        private static Map<String, Order> orderMap= new HashMap<String,Order>();
        {
            orderMap.put("1", new Order(1,2,new String[]{"water","coffee"}));
            orderMap.put("2", new Order(3,400,new String[]{"milk"}));
        }
        private static int id = 3;

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of OrdersResource
         */
        public OrdersResource() {
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves representation of an instance of ServiceCore.OrdersResource
         * @return an instance of dto.Order[]
         */
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public dto.Order[] getJson() {


            Order[] orders = new Order[orderMap.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<orderMap.size(); i++){
                orders[i]=orderMap.get((i+1)+"");
            }

            return orders;
        }

        /**
         * POST method for creating an instance of OrderResource
         * @param content representation for the new resource
         * @return an HTTP response with content of the created resource
         */
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response postJson(Order content) {
            orderMap.put(id+"", content);
            id++;
            return Response.created(context.getAbsolutePath()).build();
        }

        /**
         * Sub-resource locator method for {id}
         */
        @Path("{id}")
        public OrderResource getOrderResource(@PathParam("id") String id) {
            return OrderResource.getInstance(id,orderMap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you ensured that the server side is working properly? Could you share how you implemented the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, most web frameworks use more than one Servlet to handle requests, often discarding the servlet as soon as the request is handled.

You probably need to put your Map of items into a different context, like the Application context, which is persistent across the entire life of the Application.

Comment: The funny thing is that I used the same exact code for passing a string instead of the Order object and the static map worked. Do you know how this is possible ?